# Asp.net 5.0, Entity framework 6

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I have a .net 5.0 web Api project, I want to know that:

Does .net 5.0 support entity framework database first? I can't create an entity Model (.Edmx).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes , You can !! `From the Tools menu click NuGet Package Manager and then click Package Manager Console.

In the Package Manager Console window enter the following command:

Install-Package EntityFramework` you need to install the entity frame work first

Comment: I know. I mean. I cannot use the database first. it seem be support only code first?

Comment: can you be more clear about your point,u cannot use database means?

Comment: I can use the entity framework. But only with code first to connect to the database. I can't create a Model(.Edmx) like .net 4.5 project

Comment: u can't or unable to create?

Comment: It seem be does not support that. I don't find the Ado.net Entity Data Model in the adding items box

Comment: ah got it !! `The EDMX approach is not supported in ASP.NET 5 Class Library (Package) projects. Make sure you select the older Class Library Project template from Templates » Visual C# » Windows`